# How can i check the query string parameters for Internet Explorer in Google Analytics?

Tags: google-analytics, testing, universal-analytics, query-string, internet-explorer-10

I am testing Google Analytics query string parameters in Internet Explorer 10.
I am unable to find the required attributes in Network Tab.
Any help?

Would any add-ons help me?

Comment: Can you clarify "testing Google Analytics query string parameters"? Are you trying having issues with Campaign/Medium/Source parameters or are you wanting pages with query strings to show up as their own unique page view?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I came up with an answer finally after an year.
now i am using HTTP watch extension.

https://www.httpwatch.com/download/

Go to the above URL and download the free edition. Run the .exe file.
Then you can add the extension in either firefox or IE or both.

After the process you should be able to find the HTTPwatch option on your right click given on IE browser.
You can check the query string parameters in a user friendly manner.

for more info you can check the guide available on the above URL

Answer (score 1):

I am struggling with GA too. I cannot find the query string parameters in IE, but I can use the Developer Tool in Chrome. Click the Network tab and filter the GIF file sent to Google server, then click the name of GIF file and click on the header. On the bottom you can see Query String Parameters that lists all the parameters. Then you can compare that with the link [here](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/protocol/v1/parameters) to see if you have everything you want.

Comment: Thank you Chris. The GIF file actually helped to find all query string parameters at once place. The saved file is not so user friendly, but still helps me to some extent.

Answer (score 0):

Then you can use fiddler
http://www.telerik.com/download/fiddler

Then check the GET request done when retriving the ga.js file

Comment: No helpful if the original post was about IE :P

Comment: Check above ;) .

Comment: Fiddler didnt help me.
I didnt find required parameters in Fiddler.

Also i can elobarate my question. As a part of testing i need to check the event cateory, Action, Hit type, UA id's etc.. attributes in console.
I am struggling to check the required attributes after the tag has been fired.
Any help?

Comment: Then move yourself to Google Tag Manager and include from there your GA uid. GTM's dataLayer object is tracking any event fired with all its parameters.